# Can i edit the range price layer by code?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, price, error

My catalog product use 3 Columns Layout:

The layered navigation in the right
The product in the center
The cart in the left

All work very well but i have a problem when that the maximum price of product in the category are lower than the range price, the layered Navigation is not displayed and the left section is empty.

For example, if in my category i have five products and the maximum price between there products are $70.00 and the range price is 100 i have this problem.

I know that the range can be edited in admin panel : system>configuration>catalog>layered navigation.

I found the file when magento return me the range : /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php

```
 public function getPriceRange()
    {
        $range = $this->getData('price_range');
        if (is_null($range)) {
            $maxPrice = $this->getMaxPriceInt();
        $index = 1;
            do {
                $range = pow(10, (strlen(floor($maxPrice))-$index));
                $items = $this->getRangeItemCounts($range);
                $index++;
            }
            while($range>self::MIN_RANGE_POWER && count($items)<2);

            $this->setData('price_range', $range);
        }
        return $range;
    }
```

Can i edit this code to adapt in my situation. Can edit the price range according the maximum product price in the category ?

or if i have this problem can i transform my catalog design from 3 Columns Layout to 2 Columns Layout with any code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to set this using code? Via Catalog > Manage Categories you can set a price range per category. So if your most expensive product is $70, just set the range to a lower number and all should work just fine.